# IBM MobileFirst 7.1 with Android Cordova failure when init JSONStore

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app, jsonstore

I am trying to create a 'heloworld' project with IBM Mobilefirst 7.1 integrate cordova using platform android and enable feature JSONStore

- Step 1: create mobilefirst cordova project flowing link https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/hello-world/integrating-mfpf-sdk-in-cordova-applications/#sampleApplication 
   Note: platform android and add more plugin jsonstore
- Step 2: add feature JSONStore in application-descriptor.xml
- Step 3: add code in function wlCommonInit

  ```
  WL.JSONStore.init(collections).then(function (collections) {
      // handle success - collection.people (people's collection)
      console.log('ok')
  }).fail(function (error) {
      // handle failure
      console.log('error', error)
  });
  ```
- Step 4: build and run with Android studio with Android Emulator - Nexus_4_API_19, I get error of console.log('error', error)

  ```
  col: "people"
  doc: Object
  err: -1
  msg: "PERSISTENT_STORE_FAILURE"
  res: Object
  src: "initCollection"
  usr: "jsonstore"
  ```

  console log in Android Studio

> I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(44)] "Calling WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions);", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-mfp/bootstrap.js (44) 
>   W/PluginManager: THREAD WARNING: exec() call to DeviceAuth.getDeviceUUID blocked the main thread for 181ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
>   D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb8eea440: ver 2 0
>   I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(17)] "1", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js (17)
>   D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb8eea440: ver 2 0
>   I/dalvikvm: Could not find method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable, referenced from method com.worklight.wlclient.push.common.GCMClientFactory.useGooglePlayServices
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 631: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable (Landroid/content/Context;)I
>   D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0006
>   D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 748K, 13% free 6159K/7012K, paused 10ms, total 12ms
>   D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 163840
>   D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /data/data/com.ibm.testjsonstore/files/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 0xa4fcd670
>   D/dalvikvm: Added shared lib /data/data/com.ibm.testjsonstore/files/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 0xa4fcd670
>   D/dalvikvm: No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.ibm.testjsonstore/files/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 0xa4fcd670, skipping init
>   I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(29)] "erorr", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js (29)

Anyone know about this, please help

Comment: Are you using any push service? Also can you share your sample app? We do not see any issues when trying to recreate your problem.

Comment: Thanks for response Keerthi, any push service, you mean 'mfp push' command, yes, then I run with simulator with android studio. The sample app very large, so I wonder how about to share. But do you ever created hello world IBM Mobilefirst 7.1 project  with enable JSONStore ? Do it init sucessful?

Comment: Yes, a simple hello world of MFP 7.1 jsonstore does init successfully. Your issue is more likely to be due to incompatible versions of your simuator's android api and the GCM libraries. Could you try on a different emulator or device and report?

Also you could upload the project to github and share the link here.

Comment: I also try simulator API 22, real android device version 6. and 7., it get the same error. I just upload project to https://gitlab.com/pt.long/testjsonstore. My IBM mobilefirst version 7.1.0.00.20160801-2318. Can you tell me know what android API and mfp version do you use in your simple helloworld successfully?

Comment: The app that you have shard does not have the plugins folder. Could you upload the complete app?

Comment: I just commit, please try :)