# IBM MobileFirst CLI 7.1 older release

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm working with IBM MobileFirst 7.1, version 7.1.0.00.20160801-2318, this version have problem as [IBM MobileFirst 7.1 with Android Cordova failure when init JSONStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48019338/ibm-mobilefirst-7-1-with-android-cordova-failure-when-init-jsonstore), so I try a newer CLI version to fix a problem, then I download newest MobileFirst Platform Foundation CLI v7.1 from https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/downloads/ (IF20171213-0650), but this release have problem with cordova command as IBM confirmed, they said they will fix in upcomming release, but I don't know when next CLI release?

Please help me to download CLI 7.1 release >7.1.0.00.20160801-2318 and

Answer (score 0):

IBM just release new CLI (IF20180105-1108) to fix this problem
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/downloads/
Thanks.